# Rest Api data fetching error while using chartjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, chart.js, data-visualization

I have question related to the data **fetching of api in which I have to represent the data in chartjs** or in the format of data visualization.
I am trying to use this api as a source to represent the data in charting format to get ready up my dashboard which is being ready for the data analysis perspective. Please help me, I know I am lagging with a little part.

1. App.js

   ```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
   import axios from "axios";

   import Chart from "./chart";

   class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      labels: [],
      data: []
     };
   }

    componentDidMount() {
     this.getChartData();
   }

   getChartData() {
    Date.formatMMDDYYYY = () => {
      return (
        this.getDate() + 1 + "/" + this.getMonth() + "/" + 
           this.getFullYear()
      );
    };

    axios
      .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.myjson.com/bins/chnmi"
     )
     .then(results => {
       // Split timestamp and data into separate arrays
        const labels = [];
        const data = [];
        results.forEach(packet => {
          labels.push(new Date(packet.updated).formatMMDDYYYY());
          data.push(parseFloat(packet.users));
        });

        this.setState({ data, labels });
        })
        .catch(error => {
         console.log(error);
        });
     }

     render() {
       return (
         <div>
          <Chart labels={this.state.labels} data={this.state.data} />
         </div>
       );
     }
    }

    export default App;
   ```
2. chart.js

   ```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';

    class Chart extends Component {
      render() {
        const chartData = {
           labels: this.props.labels,
           datasets: [
                       {
                         data: this.props.data,
                         backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                        }
                     ]
                  }
           return (
              <div className="chart">
                <Bar 
                   data={chartData}
                   options={{
                       title: {
                           display: true,
                           text: 'Largest cities in Delhi',
                           fontSize: 25
                       },
                       legend: {
                           display: true,
                           position: 'right'
                        }
                      }}
                   />
               </div>
             );
           }
         }

         export default Chart;
   ```

Comment: What is the error you're having?

Comment: I couldn't able to show the data in chartjs format. I want to represent the data. You can check this link for more: https://codesandbox.io/embed/82y7nl2pl0?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to inherit a new custom method to the instances of an object, you need to define them in the prototype, so instead of `Date.formatMMDDYYYY = () => {...}` use this `Date.prototype.formatMMDDYYYY = function{...}`, we can't use arrow functions because then we won't get the right values for `this`. Also you could have used instead a normal function that received a Date and call it whenever you need it, this way was more easy and safe.
2. Small error about the order in the format string the method is returning, instead of `this.getDate() + 1 + "/" + this.getMonth() +...` it should be `this.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + this.getDate() +...`
3. You are trying to get the data from `results`, but data is not there it's in `results.data`, so the cycle should be `results.data.forEach(packet => {...}`

Fixed code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/p3q2pz2l8x

Comment: you're welcome, and if you have no more doubts, could you mark the answer as accepted? thank you :)